# tsql returns the right answer only when I specify the criteria in the where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have some sql that will not return the rows I need unless I specify that as a criteria in the where clause. If I uncomment the part below that is commented out, it will give me the rows I want. If I leave it commented out, those rows are not returned in my result set.

Does this make sense? Can anyone see anything I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
SELECT     
   RTRIM(c.comp2) + '-' + l.Loc_Name, 
   MAX(RTRIM(g.mega_location_num) + '-' + g.mega_location_name) 
FROM       
   mkt_share_comp c, gldm_location g, mkt_share_locs l 
WHERE     
   RTRIM(c.comp1) = g.location_num
   AND c.comp2 = l.Loc_No
   AND LEN(c.comp2) = 5 AND c.is_deleted = 0 AND l.is_deleted = 0
   --and  g.mega_location_num = '450'
GROUP BY
   RTRIM(c.comp2) + '-' + l.Loc_Name
ORDER BY
   MAX(RTRIM(g.mega_location_num) + '-' + g.mega_location_name)
```

Comment: do you get more rows or less when you have that line commented?

Comment: I get more rows when I have that line commented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comparison:

```
MAX(RTRIM(g.mega_location_num) + '-' + g.mega_location_name)
```

Will be doing a `MAX` based on the *string* value that you're constructing. So if there are any `g.mega_location_num` values which start with a digit greater than `4` (or start with `4` and have a second digit greater than `5`, etc), then that value will be the `MAX` value returned.

To start to fix this, I would first switch to the ANSI join style that Kuya has [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13915976/15498). I would then consider including an appropriate [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) expression to locate the "genuine" maximum value from the `g` table and to be able to retrieve multiple columns from that maximal row (to allow the string construction to proceed)